# Why dont receive data if i have await

Tags: c#, linq

i would like understand how its possible.
I have in my project one linq cannot wait for response of api of twitch, and i would like understand why cannot waiting?

```
System.Threading.Timer _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 120000);

private static async void TimerCallback(Object o)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

    lstTwitch.ToList().ForEach(async item =>
    {
        if (item.PathsImagem == null)
            item.PathsImagem = await Twitch.CollectImage(item.idUser.ToString());
        TwitchStream dataStream = await Twitch.CollectDataOfStream(item.idUser.ToString());
        if (Convert.ToDateTime(dataStream.started_at) != Convert.ToDateTime(item.UltimaStream))
        {

        }
    });
}
```

Twitch.CollectDataOfStream:
[image: Twitch.CollectDataOfStream]

The problem is not in request api, but is the time of linq give to receive data. When start request on api he return on line of `TwitchStream dataStream = await Twitch.CollectDataOfStream(item.idUser.ToString());`

Comment: Side note: `async void` often is a *bad practice*, `async Task` is a better signature here

Comment: @AmanB no... but th

Comment: @DmitryBychenko i know but my project need async void "System.Threading.Timer _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 120000);" because the function where i call is static

Comment: @Carl - Did you notice the compiler warning that your `async` method contains no `await`?

Comment: @Enigmativity no? But i have await before the call

Comment: @Carl - No, you do not. In the `private static async void TimerCallback(Object o)` method you do not have an `await`. Only in the `async item =>` anonymous method do you have any awaits.

Comment: The current code starts a bunch of tasks and never awaits them. In .NET (Core) 5 and later you can use `await Parallel.Foreach(lstTwitch,async item=>{....})` to asynchronously process multiple items concurrently

Comment: @Enigmativity what can i do? I cannot remove void because the main() is static

Comment: @Carl - It won't solve your problem, but the signature of your method should be `private static void TimerCallback(Object o)` to avoid the compiler warning.

Comment: @Carl - What type is `idUser`?

Comment: @Enigmativity int